# asp.net InvalidOperationException when i use HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, keep-alive

Here is my code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // create new http request
    public void createRequest(String url, int idleTime){
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = idleTime;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createRequest("http://freemusic.somee.com/Service.asmx/add", 100000);
    }

    private void txtOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webRequest == null)
        {
            sumTxt.Text = "HTTP cannot keep alive!";
            createRequest("http://freemusic.somee.com/Service.asmx/add", 100000);
        }
        // client send a request
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        String strParameter = "a=" + aTxt.Text + "&b=" + bTxt.Text;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strParameter);
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStreamWriter = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStreamWriter.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        //dataStreamWriter.Close();

        // receive response from server
        try
        {
            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStreamReader = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataStreamReader, Encoding.UTF8);
            String strResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sumTxt.Text = strResponse;
            //webResponse.Close();
            //dataStreamReader.Close();
            //sr.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            String response = ex.Message;
            sumTxt.Text = response;
        }
    }
```

I want to create a http keep-alive connection. 'add' method in web service will receive sum of 2 input parameters a & b. It ran exactly at first, but later program threw InvalidOperationException in line : webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length; . How should i do in this case?

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: This property cannot be set after writing has started.

Comment: i think this httpWebRequest has been closed after receive response form server

Comment: Yes; you cannot reuse a `WebRequest`.

Comment: My purpose is making a persistent connection to the Internet resource and i think keep-alive property can do that. Any suggestion for me ???

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` should do that automatically.  See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_Connection.cs